# subprocess how to use command when shell = False

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I am able to run this code:

```
subprocess.call(" ./ApiStreamingClient.py -w flow-index -n admin -p admin localhost 1477389500000000000 1477389900000000000 | gzip - > out2.gz", shell=True)
```

but I would like to run it with option `shell=False` in two steps. How can I do that? I'm not able to find any simple example.

I think I need to split the command in two parts separated by `|` but I could not understand how.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve by splitting it? Splitting it would require you to receive the output of `ApiStreamingClient.py` and send it into `gzip`.

Comment: note: I'm probably wrong about this,  but I believe one thing that running it in a shell does is handles executable resolution, so when you do `./` you would instead need to pass the whole path of the python executable then the .py file as an argument and use the full path of gzip, but again I could be wrong.

Comment: The values `1477389500000000000 1477389900000000000` are start and end time of an interval. I need to run a for loop that repeats the command in several subintervals

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: You're not wrong, it's a good point.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it this way:

```
import gzip
import subprocess
import sys

command = [
    sys.executable,
    'ApiStreamingClient.py',
    '-w', 'flow-index',
    '-n', 'admin',
    '-p', 'admin',
    'localhost',
    '1477389500000000000',
    '1477389900000000000',
    ]
text = subprocess.check_output(command)
with gzip.open('out2.gz', 'w', 6) as outfile:
    outfile.write(text)
```

Note that without a shell, you can't just invoke a Python script as an executable--you need to invoke `python` directly and pass the script as an argument.  But that's easy enough.

If you want to do the whole thing in streaming fashion (e.g. if `text` takes up too much memory), you can use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to get a handle to read from, and pass that to `shutil.copyfileobj()` instead of writing `text` all at once.

Comment: wouldn't you also need to supply the whole path to the `python` executable? Like using `sys.executable` instead of just `'python'`?